# Extract Text from Two Bounding Boxes based on their Coordinates

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

One question regearding the extraction of Text from multiple bounding boxes. Lets say, I already have the coordinates of two bounding boxes (image 1):

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqVih.png)

Now I want to loop over these two different coordinates and output only the content of this bounding box.

The coordinates for these two specific bounding boxes are e.g.,
928 271 68 16 and 1039 271 48 16

The coordinates are stored here:

```
# get x, y, w, h coordinates in lists for zipping.
    x_coor = [item for item in roi[0]]
    y_coor = [item for item in roi[1]]
    w_coor = [item for item in roi[2]]
    h_coor = [item for item in roi[3]]
```

I wanted to output them by using a loop such as:

```
for x, y, w, h in zip(x_coor, y_coor, w_coor, h_coor):
    # print(x, y, w, h)
    ROI = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv.imshow("Detected ROI", ROI)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    upi_string = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI)
    upi_roi = upi_string.lower()
    print(upi_roi)
```

OpenCV is recognising only these two bounding boxes (which is good) and opens two windows that show the content of the bounding box, however the code below (last three lines) from Pytesseract is not working somehow, which means there is no output of these two contents at all.

Question is how do I loop over this so that Pytesseract only outputs the content of the two bounding boxes?

Comment: The ROIs are cropped exactly on the edges of the characters. Try cropping them with some space around the characters

Comment: your code would benefit greatly from using `numpy`. -- further, those listcomps are superfluous. just say `x_coor = roi[0]`... and why would that even be the case? what does `roi` look like?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz good point. `ROI` is a 3d `numpy.ndarray`.